# log transformation for dummies

Tags: logarithms, transformation

I have a question which is probaly very simple to answer for most people here:

We have a formula:

```
 y = -log(x)
```

Then this happens to x:

```
   = -log(x^1.5)  or ( = -log(x^(15/10)) )
```

How do I now write up y?

Many thanks!

Comment: use the formula : $\log(a^b)=b\log(a)$ (i hope the question was to rewrite the second expression in terms of $y$)

Comment: @AmireBendjeddou Sorry for not being clear. Actually, I don't want to rewrite the second expression in terms of y, but I want to do the same to y as I did to x, while still `y = -log(x)`.

Comment: you made this trandsformation : $x \rightarrow x^{1.5 } $ so you are looking for $y^{1.5 } $?? (be more explicit please)

Comment: Sorry was not thinking clearly, you are right. Now I can write it as `1.5y = -log(x^1.5)`. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can make use of the following property of $\log$:
$$\log(a^b) = b\log(a)$$

So, in this case:
$$y = -\log(x)$$
$$y = -\log(x^{1.5}) = -1.5\log(x)$$

---

Note: I treated the above as if $y$ were a function of $x$, and we applied the transformation $x \mapsto x^{1.5}$. If this isn't a transform problem:

If $y = -\log(x)$, then:
$$-\log(x^{1.5}) = -1.5\log(x) = 1.5(-\log(x)) = 1.5(y)$$
Thus:
$$1.5(y) = -\log(x^{1.5})$$

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation! Looking at your answer I realize that I did not mean a transform problem. My question is answered by the second part, so 1.5(y)=-log(x^1.5).

Comment: @Rob glad I could help. :)